Where do i connect a common wire?
I'm trying to install a nest wifi thermostat and I can't figure out where to connect the blue common wire. I've attached a pic of my ac setup and I'm hoping someone can tell me where it goes! This is a Payne(literally) . It's an ac only and it's an outside contained unit that blows and pulls air through 2 round ducts

Please post your pictures to imgur and post a link to them here, so we can edit them into your post :)

If you have the Blue common wire, connect it to the terminal marked C or Rc on Nest
